# Cent OS - sysctl.conf not working

Tags: linux, tcp, centos

The settings i have applied in my sysctl.conf are not working. Not on reboot or after applying it using sysctl -p

Below are my sysctl.conf settings. Can someone take a look and tell me what may be causing the issue?

```
#  Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0

# Controls source route verification
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1

# Do not accept source routing
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0

# Controls the System Request debugging functionality of the kernel
kernel.sysrq = 0

# Controls whether core dumps will append the PID to the core filename.
# Useful for debugging multi-threaded applications.
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1

# Controls the use of TCP syncookies
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

# Controls the default maxmimum size of a mesage queue
kernel.msgmnb = 65536

# Controls the maximum size of a message, in bytes
kernel.msgmax = 65536

# Controls the maximum shared segment size, in bytes
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736

# Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
kernel.shmall = 4294967296

net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 4

net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 2

net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 4

net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control= cubic

net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1

net.ipv4.route.flush = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_orphan_retries = 0

net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 400000

net.core.optmem_max = 10000000

net.core.rmem_default = 10000000

net.core.rmem_max = 10000000

net.core.somaxconn = 100000

net.core.wmem_default = 10000000

net.core.wmem_max = 10000000

net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1

net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535

net.ipv4.tcp_ecn = 0

net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 12000

net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 2000000

net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 10240 8738000 825829120

net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 10240 8738000 825829120

net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 10240 8738000 825829120

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 768000

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_generic_timeout = 4

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 4

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 4

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 4

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 4

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_last_ack = 4

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent = 4

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv = 4

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close = 4
```

Comment: Are you using an alternate iptables(netfilter) based firewall? Firewall's such as APF load their own locked down sysctl settings.